# How to find a condition to choose a specific number in the plot - matlab

Tags: matlab

[image: Xvalue versus b]
 i want a function that gives me every time i change g, the value of the select point the the data plot. How can i do that ?

```
function help = b0calc



s=0.319;
R= [0.319/0.6] ;
bb1 = linspace(0.01,10,600);
gg=0.5;  % gg = g for many values of g 


f2 = @(r,b,g) 1./(r.^2.*sqrt(1 - (b./r).^2 - (g^-2)*((2/15)*(s/R)^9 *(1./(r - 1).^9 - 1./(r + 1).^9 - 9./(8* r).*(1./(r - 1).^8 - 1./(r + 1).^8)) - (s/(R))^3 *(1./(r -1).^3 - 1./(r + 1).^3 - 3./(2* r).* (1./(r - 1).^2 - 1./(r + 1).^2)))));

X_scalar_b_scalar_g = @(b,g)real(pi - 2*b*quadgk(@(r)f2(r,b,g),rmin(g,b,R),Inf,'AbsTol',1e-4,'RelTol',1e-4,'MaxIntervalCount',5000));



 for j=1:length(bb1)
 Xg(j)=X_scalar_b_scalar_g(bb1(j),gg);
 end
 figure(1);
 plot(bb1,Xg)


end

 function r = rmin(g,b,R)
    s=0.319;

    f1 =  @(r)  1 - (b./r).^2 - (g^-2)*((2/15)*(s/R)^9 *(1./(r - 1).^9 - 1./(r + 1).^9 - 9./(8*r).*(1./(r - 1).^8 - 1./(r + 1).^8)) -(s/R)^3 *(1./(r-1).^3 - 1./(r+1).^3 - 3./(2*r).*(1./(r-1).^2 - 1./(r+1).^2)));
    r = fzero(f1,[1.0000001,9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999]);
 end
```

for every change of gg=g , the graphic has a singularity in y coordinate ... i want the x value that gives this singularity every time.

Comment: Can you assume the singularity always has the globally lowest value?

Comment: If it is not always the global minima, you might be interested in `findpeaks()`: https://ch.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/findpeaks.html Inverse the data (multiply it by -1) to find local minima. If there can be multiple peaks, take the one with the highest prominence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the sign change in the first derivative to track it

```
 function [sng_pos, sng_val, dydx] = first_derivative(x,y)
    % First derivative - first order forward difference
    h = x(2)-x(1);      
    dydx = diff(y)/h;
    % Find sign change then lowest function value in that range
    ing = find(dydx <= 0);
    sng_ind = find(y==min(y(max(ing)),y(max(ing)+1)));
    sng_pos = x(sng_ind);
    sng_val = y(sng_ind);
 end
```

This assumes that the singularity is present in the first minima - global or local. It treats the singularity as the lowest function value between the two derivative values with opposite signs.

Note that this uses a first order, forward difference scheme - better results can be obtained with higher order schemes and a refined grid. Second order centered scheme may already be significantly superior.

Example of usage in the main function:

```
 [s_pos, s_val, dydx] = first_derivative(bb1,Xg);

 fprintf('Position of singularity: %f and value: %f \n', s_pos, s_val)

 figure(2)
 plot(bb1(1:end-1), dydx)
 title('First derivative')
```

Comment: thanks for your answer ... but the singularity goes do - infinity, that is a problem ? in the graphic we cant see that, but the y axis goes to - infinity

Comment: You're welcome :) With your current dataset you're not getting to infinity. Even when I refine it right around that region I'm still getting function values like -10.7. Also, I think things get odd around singularities, but I don't have experience with that. You can get a closer result, within your working precision, by for instance iterative refinement of the narrow region around the singularity. Are you interested in closer approximation to where the singularity happens or just want to account for it so the program doesn't behave unexpectedly?

Comment: thanks for your help ... i just wondering how could i use the s_pos value for many different values of gg ... so how can i use s_pos(gg)  ?? i will use s_pos(gg) in a integration limits , for a integral variating in gg

Comment: Ok, I see now - you can just create an array of gg values, an array of s_pos values and call the derivative function for each set. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: g = gg is given by the program ... i have to create a function called for example s_pos(g) and put this function in a integration limits, and the program will change the g value in every iteration. but i do not know how to do it .. if you can, help me please ... but i am very thankfull to you

Comment: Your function that does the integration can call the singularity finding function all the same i.e. it can change g every iteration and call s_pos(g) to check the new position.

Comment: for example if i have this :   quadgk (@(x)  x + 1, s_pos(g), 10 ) ...  i cant put your program to find s_pos  , or i cant just write s_pos(g) in the integration limits ,  i have to make a function for s_pos(g) and then put it in the integration limits .. right ? that i can not know ..   the g value is given by the program in another integral ...

Comment: No, doesn't seem you can call it directly from the limits but you can reassign it to a variable and just use that variable, i.e. `lim_0 = s_pos(g)`, `quadgk (@(x) x + 1, lim_0, 10 )`. Also, you don't need to use anonymous functions in quadgk, any other functions will do - you just need the function handle like `quadgk (@fun_name, x0, 10 )`.